# Error with compiling Terrform custom provider related to GRPCProviderServer

Tags: terraform, azure-custom-providers

In the process of building Terraform custom provider using `terraform-plugin-framework`. After updating bunch of dependencies, hit the following snag:

```
> make build
env GOOS=`uname | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` GOARCH=amd64 GO111MODULE=on go build -o terraform-provider-core_v3.0.0_x1 -gcflags="all=-N -l" -ldflags "-X=main.Version=3.0.0 -X=main.Build=1"
# github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema
vendor/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema/provider.go:508:9: cannot use NewGRPCProviderServer(p) (value of type *GRPCProviderServer) as tfprotov5.ProviderServer value in return statement: *GRPCProviderServer does not implement tfprotov5.ProviderServer (missing method GetMetadata)
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Since I'm using Terraform Framework (instead of SDK), this reference should not even be there `terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema/provider.go`

I tried removing `./vendor` directory and downloading all packages from scratch, but the issue still persists. Appreciate any help.

Comment: As you can definitely ascertain from your linked GH issue I am super familiar with this issue, but I believe this was also fixed in the latest version of the plugin testing module as that specifies SDKv2 v2.30.0 as a dependency last time I checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution for this issue. Apparently this happened due to Go dependency super weird situation, for more details see this [framework issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-framework/issues/861).

And the way it gets resolved by manually updating version of `github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2` package in `go.mod` to set as `v2.30.0` like so

```
go 1.19

require (
...
    github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2 v2.30.0
...
)
```

Keep in mind, if you try to build the code right after manual version update of the package, it'll fail agin:

```
env GOOS=`uname | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` GOARCH=amd64 GO111MODULE=on go build -o terraform-provider-core_v3.0.0_x1 -gcflags="all=-N -l" -ldflags "-X=main.Version=3.0.0 -X=main.Build=1"
go: inconsistent vendoring in /Users/iamuser/terraform-provider-core:
    github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2@v2.30.0: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
    github.com/apparentlymart/go-textseg/v15@v15.0.0: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
    github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2@v2.19.1: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
    github.com/zclconf/go-cty@v1.14.1: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
    golang.org/x/crypto@v0.15.0: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
    golang.org/x/sys@v0.14.0: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
    golang.org/x/text@v0.14.0: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
    google.golang.org/grpc@v1.57.1: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
    github.com/apparentlymart/go-textseg/v13@v13.0.0: is marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt, but not explicitly required in go.mod
    github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2@v2.16.2: is marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt, but not explicitly required in go.mod
    github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2@v2.26.0: is marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt, but not explicitly required in go.mod
    github.com/zclconf/go-cty@v1.13.1: is marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt, but not explicitly required in go.mod
    golang.org/x/crypto@v0.14.0: is marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt, but not explicitly required in go.mod
    golang.org/x/sys@v0.13.0: is marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt, but not explicitly required in go.mod
    golang.org/x/text@v0.13.0: is marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt, but not explicitly required in go.mod
    google.golang.org/grpc@v1.57.0: is marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt, but not explicitly required in go.mod

    To ignore the vendor directory, use -mod=readonly or -mod=mod.
    To sync the vendor directory, run:
        go mod vendor
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

So, first thing you need to run is `go mod vendor` to properly update dependancies, and then, you can build the code.

Hope this helps anyone who encounters such issue.